# Run-time errors and memory leaks detection

Tags: visual-c++

Created application is working toooo slow, looks like there are a lot of memory leaks, there are a lot of pointers. So, please, can you advice some effective tool for run-time errors and memory leaks detection in Visual Studio C++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use deleaker. It must help you.

Comment: Excellent solution! Best debugger!

Answer (score 0):

If you use the debug version of the **CRT** library , you can use find all [memory leaks very easily](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x98tx3cf.aspx).

Basically after including appropriate headers you call

```
_CrtSetDbgFlag ( _CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF | _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF );
```

somewhere in the beginning of you program.

Before the program exits you should call

```
_CrtSetReportMode( _CRT_ERROR, _CRTDBG_MODE_DEBUG );
```

Which dumps all the memory leaks to Debug Output Window.

But the application being slow might be unrelated to memory leaks, For performance profiling you can follow directions as per **[Find Application Bottlenecks with Visual Studio Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc337887.aspx)**

For catching bad C++ constructs at compile time, you can use the [static code analysis feature](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d3bbz7tz.aspx) of Visual Studio 2010 or later.

Answer (score 0):

I know 2 good tools for windows: [Purify](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/awdtools/purify/) and [Insure++](http://www.parasoft.com/jsp/products/home.jsp?product=Insure).

For linux: [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/).